# External CSS: Body Background Color Won't Change

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, background-color

I cannot get my body background color to change on my Bootstrap 3 site. Here is a snippet from my external CSS file:

```
body {
font-family: 'Lato', arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5;
font-weight: 300;
color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

I have tried the following with no joy:

```
body {
background-color: #0aff0a;
font-family: 'Lato', arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5;
font-weight: 300;
color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

**- AND -**

```
body {
background-color: #0aff0a !important;
font-family: 'Lato', arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5;
font-weight: 300;
color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

**- Also -**

```
body {background: #0aff0a}
font-family: 'Lato', arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5;
font-weight: 300;
color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

**- AND -**

```
body {background-color: #0aff0a}
font-family: 'Lato', arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5;
font-weight: 300;
color: #2e2e2e;
}
```

All of the above codes test perfectly fine on fiddlesalad.

I have even tried adding the following directly to my html file's head:

```
<style>
body {
background-color: #0aff0a !important;
</style>
```

If I remove the reference to my CSS file and leave that in my html file's head, the background color changes. So, obviously there must be something overriding the body background color in my CSS file? I sure can't find it!

There is not any internal CSS on my pages that could be overriding it and my stylesheet is referenced properly and working fine. I have tried clearing my cache and i've tried viewing in multiple browsers...

Here is a link to the site i'm working on: [Sinister Serpents](http://www.sinisterserpents.com)

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you saying it would be better to copy/paste all 1600 lines of my CSS file? I thought my examples were very precise...

Answer (score 4):

In css file try overriding the background-color by !important;

```
body {
font-family: 'Lato', arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 1.5;
font-weight: 300;
background-color: #2e2e2e !important;
}
```

And make sure to link your css to your html head at last.

If this doesnt work try doing it in internal stylesheet

What to do if this also doesn't work ?
For a while hide all other sections and try it !

Goodluck !

Comment: Thanks Gururaj. As I mentioned in my original post, I already tried overriding with "!important" and it didn't work and that my CSS file is properly referenced. Also, that I tried adding the background-color property internally... Thanks, though...

Comment: If possible share the working fiddle so that we can help you

Comment: No worries open this link and paste the non working code [https://jsfiddle.net/tjtmhfcq/](https://jsfiddle.net/tjtmhfcq/) and let me know when done

Answer (score 0):

" fh5co-main " this id is overriding you background color from my point of view. I don't know what you are trying to do. Can you tel me the solution you are looking for ?

Comment: Hi Tawshif. Thank you for your reply. I already tried changing the background color on "fh5co-main" and that didn't work either. I'm simply trying to gain control over my overall body background color, so I can experiment with different background colors and possibly textures. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: This is really blowing my mind. I copy/pasted my entire css file at fiddlesalad and anyone of the background-color codes I listed above change the background color just fine. Yet, it refuses to work on the site...

Comment: removing the background / background-color  property from id="fh5co-main" should work just fine . its a better practice to write css ruls on class then id
can you share your fiddlesalad link with me . i will give it a try

Comment: I tried completely removing the background-color property from "fh5co-main" and adding it to body and still no go... I just realized that adding the background-image property to body will not work either... *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Oh jeeeez... I figured it out, guys! I logged into my CDN at cloudflare.com and purged all of my files and lo and behold the color changed fine by adding the background-color property to "fh5co-main". I was beginning to think I was olosing my mind! lol

Thanks so much for all of your help!